# staticListInParentClass.OfType<DerivedType>?

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to understand whow I could do the following.
I have an abstract class with a static list which should store objects of any derived class. Also in the abstract class I have method which should do stuff with only the objects of the calling derived class. But how can I do this? Variations of GetType() or typeof() have not been successful (can't compile).

```
    private abstract class Report
    {
        internal static List<Report> allReports;

        internal void Process()
        {
            //get list of Reports which are of the calling derived type
            List<CallingType> reportsOfCallingType = allReports.OfType<CallingType>().ToList();
            //do stuff with reportsOfCallingType
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the report class generic:

```
private abstract class Report<T> where T : Report<T>
{
  internal void Process()
    {
        List<T> reportsOfCallingType = allReports.OfType<T>().ToList();
        //do stuff with derivedReports
    }
}
```

Which looks a little strange, but is useable like so:

```
public class CallingType : Report<CallingType>
{
}
```

Or alternatively, use `Type.IsInstanceOfType` method:

```
var myReports = allReports.Where(GetType().IsInstanceOfType).ToList();
```

Comment: @SLaks It is indeed (the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) - it is good that such creative pattern names exist!

Comment: Thanks. Because, as it said in the article SLaks linked to, the CRTP has some issues, I'll try to use the alternative method.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that using generics, since you don't have a compile-time type.  (unless you use the [CRTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx))

Instead, write

```
Type myType = GetType();
List<Report> myReports = allReports.Where(myType.IsInstanceOfType).ToList();
```